# Gradle project refresh failed (Android), Not After message

Tags: android, gradle

i faced with this message when sync gradle : [image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was problem of JDK path.

I just set  path of JDK for Android Studio.

File -> Project Structure -> From Left Side Panel "SDK Location" -> JDK Location -> Click to select JDK Path.

Comment: i use recommend path for it, but change it does not solve the problem.